# Помогите создать иерархию классов с паттерном Композит. Java

Tags: java, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Мне нужно определить иерархию. Как можно применить паттерн Композит тут.
Есть классы `Disk`, `Playlist`, `Song`, `Performer`.
`Disk` состоит из коллекции `Playlist`. 
Я так полагаю `Playlist` состоит из коллекции `Song`.
`Song` не должна ничего знать о `Performer`. У него состояние - это название, жанр и продолжительность.

Класс `Song` абстрактный и его реализуют разные там конкретные классы типа `Jazz`, `Pop` и тд.

Как сделать это все хорошо, помогите, заранее спасибо! )

Answer (score 1):

Каноническая идея композита - не ставить различий между листом (Song) и веткой (Playlist). Просто вводится общий предок.

```
interface Playable { int getDurationSec(); String getTitle(); ... }
interface Song extends Playable { ... }
intreface Playlist extends Playable { void add(Playable item); void remove(Playable item); }
interface Disk extends Playlist {}
interface Performer extends Playlist {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Трудно ответить на вопрос `Как сделать все хорошо?` :)

Да и вариантов масса может быть при такой поверхностной формулировке.

Но я бы сделал так:

```
@Data
public class Disk {
    private List<Playlist> playlists;
}

@Data
public class Playlist {
    private List<Song> songs;
}

abstract public class Song {

    abstract public String getArtist();

    abstract public String getTitle();

    abstract public int getDuration();

    abstract public String getGenre();

}

@Data
abstract public class BaseSong extends Song {

    private final String artist;
    private final String title;
    private final int duration;

    public BaseSong(String artist, String title, int duration) {
        this.artist = artist;
        this.title = title;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    @Override
    public String getGenre() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

}

public class Rock extends BaseSong {
    public Rock(String artist, String title, int duration) {
        super(artist, title, duration);
    }
}

public class Jazz extends BaseSong {
    public Jazz(String artist, String title, int duration) {
        super(artist, title, duration);
    }
}

public class Performer extends Song {

    private Queue<Song> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    private volatile Song currentSong;

    public Performer() {}

    public Performer(Song song) {
        this(Collections.singletonList(song));
    }

    public Performer(Collection<Song> songs) {
        queue.addAll(songs);
    }

    public void add(Collection<Song> songs) {
        queue.addAll(songs);
    }

    public void add(Song song) {
        add(Collections.singletonList(song));
    }

    public void remove(Collection<Song> songs) {
        queue.removeAll(songs);
    }

    public void remove(Song song) {
        remove(Collections.singletonList(song));
    }

    public void play() throws InterruptedException {
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Song song = queue.poll();
            setCurrentSong(song);

            // Playing...
            Thread.sleep(song.getDuration());
        }
    }

    private void setCurrentSong(Song song) {
        synchronized (this) {
            currentSong = song;
        }
    }

    public Song getCurrentSong() {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (currentSong == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("No song is playing");
            }

            return currentSong;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getArtist() {
        return getCurrentSong().getArtist();
    }

    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return getCurrentSong().getTitle();
    }

    @Override
    public int getDuration() {
        return getCurrentSong().getDuration();
    }

    @Override
    public String getGenre() {
        return getCurrentSong().getGenre();
    }
}
```

`@Data` - аннотация [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html), чтобы не писать геттеры/сеттеры.